# How to refresh content of Left window in NappDrawer module Titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am using the NappDrawerModule (dk.napp.drawer) to show option using Table View (on the Left Window). I am trying to update content of Table view (on left view) from button on center view. Is this possible? If yes, please explain how. If not, then please suggest an alternative to do this.
To explain actual scenario in detail, I am attempting to change content of tableview in leftWindow on click of button which is on centerWindow. Here are few use cases which I have tried doing:- 1. Removing views and recreating them. (Doesn't work. It doesn't seem to remove them no matter whatever way of removing I try.) 2. I am firing custom event from centerWindow and tried updating values. It doesn't update them in view, however if I explicitly call for value e.g:
 `Ti.API.info(someLbl.text );`

It shows the updated value but this doesn't seem to take affect on view.
Please suggest your solutions. If you need more details please let me know.

Comment: could you try to update the data array of the table view and then call table.setdate (data array ) in this way you can update the content of table view

Comment: I have already tried that. If I log content of table it would show updated in that table data array, but not in the view. The issue is that the view contents are not being updated. They remains the same as were added initially to the left window of drawer when created.